# schema validation failed with the following errors

Tags: ionic-framework

I know that there are a lot of kind of this questions but mine I think that I did not see that yet.When building my android platform, this error appends.

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
 Data path ".scripts[0]" should NOT have additional properties(lazy).
 Data path ".scripts[0]" should be string.
 Data path ".scripts[0]" should match exactly one schema in oneOf.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
```

So How can I figure it out??? PLEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I moved from `@angular-devkit/build-angular` version `~0.900.0-rc.3` to version `^0.1100.2` I had the same error. Setting in `package.json` the following configuration solved my issue:

```json
 "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.0-rc.3",
```

Comment: It's do not work. U want me to "update" it to this version with a npm comand or just to modify it into my package.json. Coz I just modified it and it ain't work. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

On angular.json file if you habe an empty script tag, like this, Just remove it !

```
 "build": {
      "options": {
       ....,
       "scripts": []      <-- Remove this line
```

Comment: i have scripts in there, its not empty

Comment: I have the same issue when upgrading from angular 13 to 14, it build when I remove the script part, otherwise it's not building. ```ng build
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "/scripts/0" must be object.
  Data path "/scripts/0" must match pattern "\.[cm]?jsx?$".
  Data path "/scripts/0" must match exactly one schema in oneOf.```

Answer (score 0):

For IONIC you can follow these steps :

1. Remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`.
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. `npm install`.
4. Now try to run, if it didn't work go for the next step.
5. `npm i -g npm-check-updates`
6. `ncu -u`
7. `ionic cordova platform rm android`.
8. `ionic cordova platform add android`.
9. `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error might be happening due to new syntax for script tag in `angular.json`.
Please find and update this tag (might be more than one) and update it accordingly to the new syntax:

```json
"scripts": [
   {
      "input": "a.js",
      "input": "b.js"
   }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

remove "scripts": [ ] from "architect":

add  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" in "test":  "scripts": [ ]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar Error:
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "/scripts/14" must be object.
Data path "/scripts/14" must match pattern.
Data path "/scripts/14" must be match exactly one schema in oneOf;

So what i did to solve the above error i got was to go to my angular.json, locate the "options", inside it exists a "script" where file locations are added and then removed the path added manually, as i was referencing to the JSON i created in an api folder, since the path was already existing in my **"assets"** **"src/api"** it has been automatically added when i created the **api** folder and i was not aware of it's presence.

```
      "options": {
        ...
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          ...
          **"src/api"**
        ],
        "styles": [
          ...
          "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css"
        ],
        **"scripts": [
          ...
          "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js"
        ]**
```